# Simulating an Active Directory Login in Dev/Test Environment

Tags: c#, wpf, active-directory, windows-xp, windows-authentication

Currently building a WPF app that will run in an environment where the user logs into Windows PC which is on a domain (DC).  The app will ask the user to enter their login and password again when it starts up, and the login/password will be verified against Active Directory (forgive me if my terminology is not correct here).

The login is all-or-nothing; if their password is correct, there is no (current) concern with retrieving groups, rights or anything of that nature.

The development environment is not AD-based, and is not on a domain.  Are there any options for simulating this kind of login without going through the process of setting up a domain controller and adding the development and test environment machines to it?

There will be *some* opportunity to do deployment testing during the course of the project (IOW create a test login app, deploy it to the user and make sure the login works before final deployment).  At the same time, I will need to use some sort implementation that works in the test/dev environment.

Any thoughts?  Would you recommend *against* simulating this in lieu of setting up a DC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [ADAM](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/adam/default.mspx) (Windows Server 2003 Active Directory Application Mode)

> For organizations that require
>   flexible support for directory-enabled
>   applications, Microsoft has developed
>   Active Directory Application Mode
>   (ADAM). ADAM is a Lightweight
>   Directory Access Protocol (LDAP)
>   directory service that runs as a user
>   service, rather than as a system
>   service. Active Directory Application
>   Mode represents a breakthrough in
>   directory services technology that
>   provides flexibility and helps
>   organizations avoid increased
>   infrastructure costs.

That is, a free AD server from Microsoft that you can run on your desktop.

Comment: +1 An AD server which runs as a NT service on your machine - even multiple instances at once are possible!

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Windows 8 you can go to Add/Remove Windows Features and check AD LDS. Once it's finished configuring, run mmc and add ADSI Edit. It'll default to a domain controller on the network and you can populate your own instance of AD.