# Active Directory Development Environment

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

I have a requirement to integrate an ASP.NET web application with active directory - basically they want to be able authenticate and authorize with AD.

I realise this is relatively simple, but what I want to know is how I can simulate the AD for developing and testing against. I don't have AD available to me (right now) and don't cherish the thought of setting it up even if I had hardware available to run it on.

What other options are available to me? I've seen [ADAM mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142555/simulating-an-active-directory-login-in-dev-test-environment) in a couple of places but this doesn't seem to provide the federation services I need (and seems a little out dated). Would it be possible to use Azure for this? I want to keep costs (time-wise as well as money) to a minimum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have managed to set up an active directory environment suitable for development using a Microsoft Azure VM.

A brief summary of the steps I went through to get this working are below. Although it sounds scary setting up AD and ADFS, the windows server 2012 interface makes it incredibly easier, barring a few gotcha's I mention below - it takes a while for them to install as well.

1. Create a new azure windows server 2012 VM and add endpoints for http and https.
2. Install the AD role on the VM
3. Install the ADFS role on the VM
4. Create an ASP.NET MVC 4 app (on your dev machine) and verify it is working correctly.
5. Run the app through IIS (not IIS express - this just makes SSL etc easier).
6. Ensure the site has a https binding set up
7. [Install the Identity and Access tool for VS2012](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/03/25/a-refresh-of-the-identity-and-access-tool-for-vs-2012/)
8. Right click your project to select the identity and access tool.
9. The path to the STS meta document will be `https://<your VM url>/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml` (you may need to download this file manually if your certificates are self signed).
10. Back on your VM, in ADFS create a relying party trust for your application.
11. Run your MVC app again and you should be redirected to your VM for authentication and then back to your app again (but this time using https).
12. If you are using the default MVC template, in the top right corner assuming you have set up the claims correctly, you should see Hi, <user>@<domain>

The main articles that I followed to achieve this are as follows:

http://blogs.rondewit.com/post/MVC-2b-ADFS-20-Federated-Authentication.aspx
http://garymcallisteronline.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/aspnet-mvc-4-adfs-20-and-3rd-party-sts.html

Below is a list of gotcha's that I hit (in no particular order).

1. When setting up the relying party trust enter the data manually and ensure you set the Relying part WS-Federation Passive protocol URL and the relying party trust identifiers correctly. The first is simply the https url that ADFS will redirect back to after authentication has completed - `https://localhost` for example. The second is an identifier used to identify the application that is trying to authenticate. One of the identifiers entered *must* match the realm attribute of the wsFederation node in your MVC 4 apps web.config.
2. When logging in the username should be of the form <domain>\<username>
3. I couldn't get Windows Authentication to work with any browser other than IE. For this set up to work with Chrome I had to change the order of the local authentication types in the web.config of the adfs/ls application so that forms authentication appeared first. To get to this, open up IIS manager on your VM, expand default web site/adfs/ls, right click ls and select explore.
4. At the time of writing I haven't been able to login with an AD user I created myself - I've probably just not set it up correctly. When setting this up initially, I'd suggest trying to connect with the admin user you created through the azure portal when you created the VM.
5. Once I finally managed to authenticate correctly AntiForgeryToken html helper started throwing an exception, talking about missing claims. Ensure that you have added a claim rule to your relying party trust, that sets either the name or name id claim. Then in Application_Start do the following: `AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.Name;` as explained [here](http://brockallen.com/2012/07/08/mvc-4-antiforgerytoken-and-claims/).

It is also worth noting that the Identity and Access tool allows you to setup authentication with Azure ACS and more noteworthy, a development STS. For my requirements, I need to be able to integrate with ADFS, but if you're just experimenting with claims based authentication, one of these may be a better option than the process that I have gone through above.

Answer (score 0):

Consider ADFS and ws-federation.

Ws-federation is an enterprise sso protocol that gives you cross domain authentication/authorization in a sso manner. Adfs is a free implementation of the protocol that sits on top of the active directory. It is relatively easy to set up.

But having a client application that expects a ws-federation identity provider, you can substitute the provider with any compliant provider, your own or the identityserver which is another free implementation but can use a membership provider. The completely custom implementation on the other hand would give you a chance to set up and serve an
arbitrary identities.

The is a small learning curve for this approach but benetifs are:

- cross domain sso
- support for multiple browsers for free (kerberos/ntlm based ad authentication could be unsupported on some browsers)
- works in an intranet and the internet
- support for advanced scenarios like for example you can set up your cloud Office365 to authenticate against your local adfs
- adfs 2.0 is free component dowloadable from msdn

Comment: Thanks for your answer Wiktor. I will indeed be using ADFS. How do I set up a development environment to test this integration however?

Comment: The easiest way would be to set up your own custom STS that mimics the ADFS. There are some good tutorials, I also wrote one once http://netpl.blogspot.com/2011/08/quest-for-customizing-adfs-sign-in-web.html